# Parsing JSON response in Swift/iOS

Tags: json, swift, nsarray

I have the following JSON.

```
[{"chatId":"1","user1_id":"1212","user2_id":"8543211123","user1_name":"dave","user2_name":"daveee","user1_profile_pic":"http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/1212\/picture?type=large","user2_profile_pic":"https:\/\/scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/1212.jpg?oh=c288ac7b31a61aee751e8ddafb05e78a&oe=57DC702E","message":{"1":{"message_id":"24242241","sender":"1212","chatId":"1","text":"hello i am","timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:13:08"},"2":{"message_id":"421421","sender":"1212","chatId":"1","text":"great","timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:15:08"}}},{"chatId":"2","user1_id":"23413524635","user2_id":"1212","user1_name":"Leo","user2_name":"dave","user1_profile_pic":"https:\/\/scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/l\/t1.0-1\/1212.jpg?oh=1212&oe=579AE3AE","user2_profile_pic":"http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/1212\/picture?type=large","message":{"1":{"message_id":"21321213","sender":"1212","chatId":"2","text":"yes, hi","timestamp":"2016-05-25 15:46:57"}}}]
```

I want to loop through the `message` and for each counter, extract the values. This is my code:

```
for anItem in jsonArray as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
var chat_messages : [Message]? = nil
var count_messages = 0;
if let dataArray = anItem["message"] as? [Int : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> ] {
    for onemessage in dataArray as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
        let curr_message = Message()
        if let messageid = onemessage["message_id"] as? String {
            curr_message.id =  messageid
        }
        if let messagedate = onemessage["timestamp"] as? NSDate {
            curr_message.date = messagedate
        }
        if let messagesender = onemessage["sender"] as? String {
            curr_message.sender = messagesender
        }
        if let messagetext = onemessage["text"] as? String {
            curr_message.text = messagetext
        }
        chat_messages![count_messages] = curr_message
        count_messages = count_messages + 1
    }
}
```

The problem is that the line `if let dataArray = anItem["message"] as? [Int : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> ] {` always fails and the `if` condition is never entered.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe numbers are also stored as strings? Have you tried cast to `[String: [String: AnyObject] ]`?

Comment: Do you mean `[String : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]`

Comment: This is a shorthand form of declaring collection types. The two forms are functionally identical, but short one is preferred in Swift.

Comment: I tried, both don't work :/

Comment: Can you please provide an actual JSON? First code snippet is not a JSON.

Comment: I just edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using NSJSONSerialization, then every dictionary is of the type: `[String : AnyObject]`. So this line:

```
if let dataArray = anItem["message"] as? [Int : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> ] {
```

should be:

```
if let dataArray = anItem["message"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
```

And to loop through the message dictionaries inside `dataArray` you could replace:

```
for onemessage in dataArray as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
```

with:

```
for (_, messageDictionary) in dataArray {
    if let onemessage = messageDictionary as? [String : AnyObject] {
```

and the rest of your code to get the various values out of the `onemessage` dictionary should work as you have it written now, except that this line will crash:

```
chat_messages![count_messages] = curr_message
```

Because you are forced unwrapping `chat_messages`, which you initialized as nil:

```
var chat_messages : [Message]? = nil
```

instead of as an empty array:

```
var chat_messages = [Message]()
```

Comment: How would I loop through it tho? I need to somehow get past the "1" , "2" etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful answer :)

Comment: One problem, I get an index out of bounds exception on                             `chat_messages[count_messages] = curr_message` after I added the last line of your solution

Comment: @mankee try removing `count_messages` entirely and replace `chat_messages![count_messages] = cur_message` with `chat_messages.append(cur_message)`